# jQuery progress bar with timezone/start date/end date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, progress-bar

I am using this:

```
var start = new Date();
var maxTime = 835000;
var timeoutVal = Math.floor(maxTime/100);
animateUpdate();

function updateProgress(percentage) {
    $('#pbar_innerdiv').css("width", percentage + "%");
    $('#pbar_innertext').text(percentage + "%");
}

function animateUpdate() {
    var now = new Date();
    var timeDiff = now.getTime() - start.getTime();
    var perc = Math.round((timeDiff/maxTime)*100);
      if (perc <= 100) {
       updateProgress(perc);
       setTimeout(animateUpdate, timeoutVal);
      }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6h74c/3/

And it works. But it only works when you load the page and starts calculating the `maxTime` (which is in miliseconds). Which is useless. I need to set starting date and ending date e.g. 3 days and 5 hours (including timezone and when entering date, need to include also hours). So if user visits in 2 days, he would already see the progress bar ~70% complete, and so on.

This is a progress bar for a site under construction. So we could let visitors know how long till the site is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are. Let start in UTC timezone.

```js
// year,month,day,hours,minutes,seconds,millisec
// set to recent UTC time in past.
var start = new Date(Date.UTC(2015, 6, 4, 7, 23, 0, 0));
var maxTime = 835000;
var timeoutVal = Math.floor(maxTime / 100);
animateUpdate();

function updateProgress(percentage) {
  $('#pbar_innerdiv').css("width", percentage + "%");
  $('#pbar_innertext').text(percentage + "%");
}

function animateUpdate() {
  var now = new Date();
  var timeDiff = now.getTime() - start.getTime();
  var perc = Math.round((timeDiff / maxTime) * 100);
  console.log(perc);
  if (perc <= 100) {
    updateProgress(perc);
    setTimeout(animateUpdate, timeoutVal);
  } else { // It got 100%
    updateProgress(100);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pbar_outerdiv" style="width: 300px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid grey; z-index: 1; position: relative; border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px;">
  <div id="pbar_innerdiv" style="background-color: lightblue; z-index: 2; height: 100%; width: 0%;"></div>
  <div id="pbar_innertext" style="z-index: 3; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; color: black; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">0%</div>
</div>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Hi, but where do I put start date of the progress bar and end date?

Comment: I updated with full example. Refresh page many times to see effect.

Comment: Why month is 6? Also what I meant that maybe I should throw maxTime out and replace it with end date. So if start date 2015-07-03 and end date 2015-07-05 then today the progress bar would show 50%.

Comment: Remember that month is zero based index (start with 0 for Jan). So if you want July, then month will be (7 - 1).

Comment: Aha, interesting. So how do I set just end date then? Because now I have to set start date and calculate in miliseconds the end date?

Comment: I think end date is not necessary because you have check `if (perc <= 100)`. Then it do not update percent anymore.

Comment: My timezone is GMT+3 I set the date to UTC(2015, 6, 4, 7, 36, 0, 0) and maxTime 120000 (so that's 2 minutes) so it means progress bar should fill in two minutes, but it stays at 0%.

Comment: I add some code  `else {
        updateProgress(100);
    }` to show that it got 100%.

Comment: Have you tried loading it on plain .html file? Give it new time with a little of processed time and load the page and it stays at 0% and then after about 30-60 seconds it jumps to it's current real percentage. It works on JSFiddle fine, but not on plain .html, something is not right.

Comment: setTimeout doesn't call on page load, after loading page you have to wait till next setTimeout call only then it updates to current percent state. Somehow I need to call setTimeout on page load immediately when HTML was loaded.

Comment: @midts: let wrap the code in `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`